# Finding polynomial $p(x)$ with satisfy $x^2-2x+2\leq p(x)\leq 2x^2-4x+3\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $p(11) = 181.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $p(x)$ be a quadratic equation with real coefficient  satisfying $$x^2-2x+2\leq p(x)\leq 2x^2-4x+3\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$ and $p(11) = 181.$ Then $p(16)= $

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can Write Inequality as $$(x-1)^2+1\leq p(x)\leq 2(x-1)^2+1$$

Here from above inequality we have seen that vertices's of $p(x)$ must lie on $\bf{1^{st}}$ quadrant and upward parabola is formed

Now I did not Understand how can I solve after that

Help me, Thanks

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2010_AIME_I_Problems/Problem_6

Answer (score 3):

Note that $p(x) - 1$ is a polynomial that satisfies

$$(x - 1)^2 \le p(x) \le 2(x - 1)^2$$

Taking limits as $x \to \infty$ (or $x \to 1$), this shows that $p$ has degree $2$, and its only zero is at $x = 1$; furthermore, this zero has multiplicity $2$. Thus, $p$ has the form

$$p(x) = c(x - 1)^2 + 1$$

for a constant $c$ between $1$ and $2$. The value $p(11) = 181$ implies that

$$c = \frac{181 - 1}{10^2} = 1.8$$

The value $p(16)$ is now easily found.

Answer (score 3):

From the given inequality it follows that the graph of $p$ is a parabola with vertice at $(1,1)$, so $p(x)=a(x-1)^2+1$, where $a>0$, then

\begin{align}
p(11)&=181\\
100a+1&=181\\
a&=\frac{9}{5}
\end{align}
Thus $$p(16)=\frac{9}{5}(16-1)^2+1=406$$